# MySQL trigger if multiple table

Tags: mysql

I will insert into table `inbox.ReceivingDateTime` when `pesanbuku.tglexp_booking == now()`.

But I'm having problems, this is my code.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER cekinbox BEFORE INSERT on inbox
BEGIN
IF pesanbuku.tglexp_booking = NOW() THEN
INSERT INTO inbox(ReceivingDateTime) values(NOW());
END IF;
END
DELIMITER
```

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to help without showing your table schema. However if you are trying to test a date time value stored in `pesanbuku.tglexp_booking` then this wont work as is. You would need to use a SELECT in your IF to get a specific value (not the whole column). Also its very unlikely NOW() will ever match up as this is to the second so you would probably want a range.

Create a variable first called @time like:

```
SET @time = SELECT tglexp_booking FROM pesanbuku WHERE something=true;
IF @time BETWEEN date1 AND date2 THEN
...
```

Comment: thank you @Mike Miller , I 'll do what you suggest.date1 AND date2, whether it can be replaced with datetime ?